# How to process a line that has 2 same words

Tags: java

I have a line as follows:
`abcde, def, efgh, mnop, mno, pqr, abc, abcde, abcde, mnop, efg`

In this, **abcde** and **mnop** occur more than once. I want to change the  names of all occurrences of **abcde** and **mnop** so that they are all represented different.

How can I do that without changing the order of the sequence?

Please note that the words that appear more than once (more than twice as well in some cases) are not known. So the need to figure out words appears more than once is to be done.

The line is a String and would want the end result as a String for processing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify on "change the names"? What's the output you're looking for?

Comment: @BoDidely - change of names could be abcde changed to firstabcde and secondabcde, depending on the occurence. Or anything that suits the context better.

Comment: Will it only ever have 2 duplicates or is there a posibility for more?

Comment: @MiiinimalLogic - It is possible to have more.

Comment: What determines the order of the sequence? In which (technical) way is the line represented (string, array, ...)?

Comment: @collapsar - it is a string.

Comment: always separated by commas?

Comment: @MiiinimalLogic - Yes!

Comment: @Vidya Can you give a sample input and sample output?

Comment: @JishnuPrathap Sample Input: abcde, def, efgh, mnop, mno, pqr, abc, abcde, abcde, mnop, efg

Sample output: firstabcde, def, efgh, mnop1, mno, pqr, abc, abcde1, abcdefirst, firstmnop, efg

Please note that they are all first or 1, but are all uniquely named.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class StringMod {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "abcde, def, efgh, mnop, mno, pqr, abc, abcde, mnop, efg, abcde";
    String[] sp = text.split(", ");
    int count = 1;
    for(int i=0;i<sp.length;i++){
        count = 1;
        for(int j=i+1;j<sp.length;j++){
            if(sp[i].equals(sp[j])){
                count++;
                sp[j]=sp[j]+" "+count;
            }
        }
    }

    String returnString = "";
    for(int i=0;i<sp.length-1;i++)
        returnString+=sp[i]+", ";
    returnString+=sp[sp.length-1];
    System.out.println(returnString);
}
}
```

Something like this should work for you ....

Input :

abcde, def, efgh, mnop, mno, pqr, abc, abcde, mnop, efg, abcde

Output :

abcde, def, efgh, mnop, mno, pqr, abc, abcde 2, mnop 2, efg, abcde 3

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Vidya  Is this close to the solution you were looking for??? It is not the best solution but should work for your problem statement.

Answer (score 2):

The important steps are:

- **split** the text by separators
- **process each item** and make it unique, if it is not yet
- **join** the text, by using the same separators

Things to consider:

- Using a `HashSet` to check, if a text is a duplicate makes your program **fast, even for long text**. My example uses `HashSet#contains`.
- Use a **loop** to make your texts unique, so that any number of occurance can be handled. *Do not use recursion*, as it has a quite limited depth and will fail on big number of occurances.
- Consider using the **Java8-Streaming API**. It allows you to use many built-in-functions of the JRE and makes your code better readable, if you add more and more logic.

The input is:

> **abcde**, def, efgh, **mnop**, mno, pqr, abc, **abcde**, **mnop**, efg

The output is:

> **abcde**, def, efgh, **mnop**, mno, pqr, abc, **abcde1**, **mnop1**, efg

My example code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class DuplicateAvoider {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // define your input
        String input = "abcde, def, efgh, mnop, mno, pqr, abc, abcde, mnop, efg";

        // create a set of unique items (intermediate result)
        Set<String> itemsUnique = new HashSet<>();

        // split input by separator pattern
        String[] items = input.split(", ");

        String output = 

                // turn items into a Java8-stream
                Arrays.stream(items)

                // "foreach" item
                .map(item -> {

                    // default items to their original text
                    String newItem = item;

                    // as long as that text is already in the list of unique items...
                    for (int i = 1; itemsUnique.contains(newItem); i++) {

                        // append a suffix-number
                        newItem = item + i;
                    }

                    // remember, that this item is now in use
                    itemsUnique.add(newItem);
                    return newItem;
                })

                // join unique items to one, separated text
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

        // print to console
        System.out.println(output);
    }

}
```

---

If you want to change the words at the beginning and leave the last occurances unchanged, then I'm suggesting to do this:

- **split** the text by separators
- **reverse** the items
- **process each item** and make it unique, if it is not yet
- **reverse** the items again (to have the original ordering)
- **join** the text, by using the same separators

The input is:

> **abcde**, def, efgh, **mnop**, mno, pqr, abc, **abcde**, **mnop**, efg

The output is:

> **abcde1**, def, efgh, **mnop1**, mno, pqr, abc, **abcde**, **mnop**, efg

The example code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class DuplicateAvoider {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // define your input
        String input = "abcde, def, efgh, mnop, mno, pqr, abc, abcde, mnop, efg";

        // create a set of unique items (intermediate result)
        Set<String> itemsUnique = new HashSet<>();

        // split input by separator pattern
        String[] items = input.split(", ");

        // reverse order of items
        List<String> itemsList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
        Collections.reverse(itemsList);

        List<String> output = 

                // turn items into a Java8-stream
                itemsList.stream()

                // "foreach" item
                .map(item -> {

                    // default items to their original text
                    String newItem = item;

                    // as long as that text is already in the list of unique items...
                    for (int i = 1; itemsUnique.contains(newItem); i++) {

                        // append a suffix-number
                        newItem = item + i;
                    }

                    // remember, that this item is now in use
                    itemsUnique.add(newItem);
                    return newItem;
                })

                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // re-reverse order of items
        Collections.reverse(output);

        // join unique items to one, separated text
        String out = output.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

        // print to console
        System.out.println(out);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way I can change the first `abcde`, rather than the second in this method?

Comment: @Vidya I updated my answer to show a way to change the first ocurrances, rather then the last occurances.

Answer (score 1):

You can split you sentence into an array of the words that appear in it by using `String.split`, then in the array of words look for words that appear more than once. change these words and rewrite the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Split string, do manipulation and build string again.

```
String myString = "abcde, def, efgh, mnop, mno, pqr, abc, abcde, mnop, efg";
String delim = ", ";
String myStrings[] = myString.split(delim);

for (int i = 0; i < myStrings.length; i++) {

    String temp = myStrings[i];

    for (int j = i + 1; j < myStrings.length; j++) {

        if (myStrings[j].equals(temp))
            myStrings[j] = temp + i;
    }
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < myStrings.length; i++) {

    if (i == myStrings.length - 1)
        sb.append(myStrings[i]);
    else
        sb.append(myStrings[i] + delim);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Output:

abcde, def, efgh, mnop, mno, pqr, abc, abcde0, mnop3, efg